# 18.04 Change graphic card drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, amdgpu

What I have to do for after changing the graphic card cin an Ubuntu 18.04 system?

I used to have a Radeon r7 260x, but I bought an NVIDIA GTX 1660 Super and want to change to it. I installed the new graphic card, booted,  uninstalled xorg-amdgpu-xxx and  installed xorg-nvidia-xxx, but the system does not recognize the new graphic card, and freezes some time after booting.

I used sudo apt remove xorg-amdgpu-xxx(I dont know exactly thy versión).

I used sudo apt install xorg-nvidia-xxx(I think was version 35, last one)

My intention was not install the nvidia propietary drivers and woks whit noveau, because I just use linux as a work station, how ever I am going to install the propietary drivers and check if this solve the problem.

Do I need to do anything else to have the new system working?

Solved: I install the propietary drivers from nvidia, and the system is working fine now. It's looks like the noveau drivers are not ready for this card or the swap make a mess with the free drivers.

Comment: The system was there, but now is in the middle to.

Comment: A) When you say _uninstalled xorg-amdgpu-xxx_, exactly what did you do? B) What command(s) were used and what was the result?  When you installed _xorg-nvidia-xxx_, C) exactly what command(s) were used and what was the result? D) Exactly which driver number did you install https://imgur.com/a/1yaB6wh after downloading from http://nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx ? Please click [edit] and add that vital infor to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: There was no need to remove or install anything. Both AMD and Nvidia free drivers are installed in every Ubuntu system.